# Passing a date to a function gives conversion to integer error

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am trying to pass a date to a function in postgres. Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.path_optimization(input_date date)
 RETURNS TABLE(area_id_ uuid, result_uuids text[])
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    
r RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- Iterate through the records in pma_ranked
    FOR r IN SELECT areaid, max_uuid FROM pma_ranked LOOP
        --RAISE NOTICE 'Processing areaid: %, max_uuid: %', r.areaid, r.max_uuid;

        RETURN QUERY
        execute format (
        '
        WITH RECURSIVE
        tree AS (
            SELECT
                g."centerPoint"::GEOMETRY AS vtcs,
                NULL::GEOMETRY AS segment,
                ARRAY[g.uuid] AS uuids
            FROM
                potential_missed_areas AS g
            WHERE
                g."areaID" = $1
                AND g.uuid = $2
                AND g.status = ''approved''
                AND g."createdAt"::date = %1$s
            UNION ALL   
            SELECT
                ST_Union(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
                ST_ShortestLine(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
                t.uuids || v.uuid  
            FROM
                tree AS t
                CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
                    SELECT
                        g.uuid,
                        g."centerPoint"
                    FROM
                        potential_missed_areas AS g
                    WHERE
                        g."areaID" = $1
                        AND g.status = ''approved''
                        AND g."createdAt"::date = %1$s
                        AND NOT g.uuid = ANY(t.uuids)
                    ORDER BY
                        t.vtcs <-> g."centerPoint"
                    LIMIT
                        1
                ) AS v
            ),
            NumberedRows AS (
                SELECT 
                    $1,uuids,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNum
                FROM tree
                WHERE segment IS NOT NULL
            )
            SELECT 
            $1,uuids
            FROM NumberedRows
            WHERE RowNum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM NumberedRows);
        '
        ,input_date)
        
        USING r.areaid, r.max_uuid;

    END LOOP;
END;
$function$
;
```

I execute the function call as such:

```
select * from public.path_optimization('2023-10-04'::date)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function path_optimization(date) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
```

I can not figure out where this date = integer condition exists. In the code above I am casting the timestamp column to date.

Update: I have added a working solution as an answer. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: To question add how you are actually calling `public.path_optimization()`. Best guess is you will need to, per error message, explicitly cast the `input_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with plain SQL. No loop, no dynamic SQL, no PL/pgSQL. No window function either.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.path_optimization(_input_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE(area_id uuid, result_uuids text[])
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
   SELECT r.areaid, r.max_uuid
        , g."centerPoint"::geometry AS vtcs
        , ST_ShortestLine(t."centerPoint"::geometry, g."centerPoint") AS segment
        , ARRAY[t.uuid, g.uuid] AS uuids
   FROM   pma_ranked r
   JOIN   potential_missed_areas t ON t."areaID" = r.areaid  -- start area
                                  AND t.uuid     = r.max_uuid
                                  AND t.status   = 'approved'
                                  AND t."createdAt"::date = _input_date  -- bad cast
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT g.uuid
           , g."centerPoint"::geometry          -- why the cast?
      FROM   potential_missed_areas g
      WHERE  g."areaID" = r.areaid
      AND    g.status = 'approved'
      AND    g."createdAt"::date = _input_date  -- bad cast
      AND    g.uuid <> t.uuid
      ORDER  BY g."centerPoint"::geometry <-> t."centerPoint"::geometry  -- bad cast (?)
      LIMIT  1
      ) g
   
   UNION ALL   
   SELECT t.areaid, t.max_uuid
        , ST_Union(t.vtcs, g."centerPoint")
        , ST_ShortestLine(t.vtcs, g."centerPoint")
        , t.uuids || g.uuid
   FROM   tree t
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT g.uuid
           , g."centerPoint"::geometry          -- why the cast?
      FROM   potential_missed_areas g
      WHERE  g."areaID" = t.areaid
      AND    g.status = 'approved'
      AND    g."createdAt"::date = _input_date  -- bad cast
      AND    g.uuid <> ALL(t.uuids)
      ORDER  BY g."centerPoint"::geometry <-> t.vtcs  -- bad cast
      LIMIT  1
      ) g
   )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
       t.areaid, t.uuids
FROM   tree t
ORDER  BY 1, 2, cardinality(t.uuids) DESC;
$func$;
```

Dynamic SQL is only required to parameterize Identifiers or code elements. Values can be passed as parameter values to plain SQL. See:

- [Syntax error in PL/pgSQL function with dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372364/syntax-error-in-dynamic-sql-in-pl-pgsql-function/48374384#48374384)
- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

The rCTE starts with the first full segment, so we don't need `WHERE segment IS NOT NULL` at the end.

I replaced the final two steps with a single query using `DISTINCT ON`. Simpler, typically faster. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Your `ROW_NUMBER()` call had no `ORDER BY`, but I assume you want the longest array from each path, so I added `cardinality(t.uuids) DESC` to the sort order.

Comment: you're right, I wanted the longest array from each path. Thanks for the alternative solution!

Answer (score 2):

Your format is not correct, you use %1$s.

> s formats the argument value as a simple string. A null value is
> treated as an empty string.

Because you're creating a SQL statement, you need quotes. And this can be done using the L:

> L quotes the argument value as an SQL literal. A null value is
> displayed as the string NULL, without quotes (equivalent to
> quote_nullable).

Simple example:

```
SELECT format('select %1$s', '2023-01-01'::date);
```

Result: select 2023-01-01
And that will be a calculation: 2023 minus 1 minus 1. An integer.

Fix:

```
SELECT format('select %1$L', '2023-01-01'::date);
```

Result:
select '2023-01-01'
And that looks like a proper date, using quotes where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Update - The following code works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.path_optimization(input_date date)
RETURNS TABLE(area_id_ uuid, result_uuids text[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    r RECORD;
    input_date_param date; -- Declare a variable to hold the input date
BEGIN
    -- Iterate through the records in pma_ranked
    FOR r IN SELECT areaid, max_uuid FROM pma_ranked LOOP
        -- Set the input_date_param to the value of input_date
        input_date_param := input_date;
        
        RETURN QUERY
        EXECUTE
        '
        WITH RECURSIVE
        tree AS (
            SELECT
                g."centerPoint"::GEOMETRY AS vtcs,
                NULL::GEOMETRY AS segment,
                ARRAY[g.uuid] AS uuids
            FROM
                potential_missed_areas AS g
            WHERE
                g."areaID" = $1
                AND g.uuid = $2
                AND g.status = ''approved''
                AND g."createdAt"::date = $3 -- Use $3 to refer to input_date_param
            UNION ALL   
            SELECT
                ST_Union(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
                ST_ShortestLine(t.vtcs, v."centerPoint"),
                t.uuids || v.uuid
            FROM
                tree AS t
                CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
                    SELECT
                        g.uuid,
                        g."centerPoint"
                    FROM
                        potential_missed_areas AS g
                    WHERE
                        g."areaID" = $1
                        AND g.status = ''approved''
                        AND g."createdAt"::date = $3 -- Use $3 to refer to input_date_param
                        AND NOT g.uuid = ANY(t.uuids)
                    ORDER BY
                        t.vtcs <-> g."centerPoint"
                    LIMIT
                        1
                ) AS v
        ),
        NumberedRows AS (
            SELECT
                $1,uuids,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNum
            FROM tree
            WHERE segment IS NOT NULL
        )
        SELECT
            $1,uuids
        FROM NumberedRows
        WHERE RowNum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM NumberedRows);
        '
        USING r.areaid, r.max_uuid, input_date_param;
        
    END LOOP;
END;
$function$;
```

The function call is the same as in the question.